# Require an object property when conditional type is combined with generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm writing a wrapper around an API. The API requires different parameters based on the type passed in. I'd like this invariant to be enforced by the TypeScript compiler without introducing any unsafe behavior, e.g. casting.

I've provided an example below of what I'm trying to do. In this analogy, `eat` is the API call, `Food` is the possible input parameters, and `Fruit` is a subset of the parameters where I want to require the caller to provide additional input. `MaybePeel` is a "helper" type that adds a `peel` property to the `EatParams` type when a `Fruit` is passed.

There are two problems with my approach, probably because of my lack of TypeScript knowledge. The first is in the method. When accessing `food.peel`, I would expect TypeScript to know that the property must exist. This works, but the problem is that TypeScript is allowing me to access that property in the `else` when the property should definitely not exist. The second is when calling the `eat` method -- TypeScript is requiring `Pizza` to provide `peel`.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAgmYBtoF4oG8oDsCGBbCAXFAERyITFQC+AUKJFAAoTYDGAFlKhjvkcczbtKtetEYBLAF5TsXdFjyESkmdhE064aADEA9noAm8skigAfJiw4Wm02VoY6ATgFcJwE-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-YioE1VRZF1JFOVlSlHi1HUmQrF8+gg9EAAFgHCABaT5IGTNT2IqCCYKLOCb2dWhnXRFC0JWaosJw104UCYJBLkI9jEwBIoDSBBmP4qT0JKaAC3CYjjDfGhqlGDB+yIHglH4ByREab0GRAIgAEZqF2dElzc+4rCEOjpigSpaQkSo3K8sC+V8pkAogILDVC8LXUixQ+EXbwKGoeK6R9UAUsaAUiGANxoCoXYgA)

```
type Apple = { name: "Apple" }
type Peach = { name: "Peach" }
type Pizza = { name: "Pizza" }

type Food = Apple | Peach | Pizza
type Fruit = Apple | Peach

// we should potentially peel fruit before eating, but we should never peel pizza (how would you even do that?)
type MaybePeel<T extends Food> = T extends Fruit ? {
  peel: boolean;
} : never;

// For Pizza, we should just take a quantity parameter; never ask to peel
// For Fruit, we should take both quantity and a `peel` boolean
type EatParams<T extends Food> = {
  food: T;
  quantity: number;
} & MaybePeel<T>

function eat<T extends Food>(params: EatParams<T>) {
  const { food } = params;

  if (food.name === "Peach" || food.name === "Apple") {
    // TypeScript should infer that `peel` must be set in this case because of `MaybePeel`
    if (params.peel) {
      // code to peel my food
    }
  } else {
    // TypeScript should throw an error here because `Pizza` never takes a `peel` parameter
    // @ts-expect-error
    params.peel
  }

  // code to eat my food
}

// Pizza should not allow `peel` to be passed in 
eat({ food: { name: "Pizza" }, quantity: 1 })
// Apple and Peach should require a `peel` to be passed in
eat({ food: { name: "Apple" }, quantity: 1, peel: true })
```

Comment: You can't do `if`/`else` analysis using generics in TS; that only works with a [discriminated union](www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), which needs the discriminant to be at the top level, not nested down inside a `food` property. So either you refactor to [something like this](//tsplay.dev/WvxLYN), or you need to write custom type guard functions [like this](https://tsplay.dev/W46GON). Which, if any, of those would you like to see in an answer? (If it's "neither", could you [edit] the question to demonstrate use cases unmet by these approaches?)

Comment: Wow thank you for taking the time for producing working examples! My worry for both of these is that they are rather confusing for me, and thus would be _very_ confusing for co-workers unfamiliar with advanced TypeScript. Of the two, the type guard option seems to be the most readable since it doesn't rely on the duplicate `foodName` option. I'll see if I can find a slightly simpler approach with the type guards, although what you have given me is excellent :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It unfortunately isn't helpful for `eat()` to be a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function.

If your `eat()` function implementation uses [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to do different things for different cases (such as with `if`/`else` or `switch`/`case`), then there's not much point making it generic in `T extends Food`.  Generic functions are more useful when you want to do a single thing that applies to multiple cases at once.

A check like `food.name === "Peach"` affects the apparent type of `food.name`, and it *might* affect the type of `food`, but it won't have any effect on the generic type parameter `T`.

There are various open feature requests asking for better for generic type parameters with support control flow analysis, such as [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) and [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014), but for now they're not part of the language.  So in what follows I'm going to forget about making `eat()` generic.

---

Instead of generics, you should probably use [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).  So `EatParams<T>` would change to just `EatParams`, a union with one member corresponding to each distinct way to call it.  You could do that manually:

```
type EatParams =
  { food: Apple; quantity: number; peel: boolean; } |
  { food: Peach; quantity: number; peel: boolean; } |
  { food: Pizza; quantity: number; };
```

or you could reuse your `Food`, `Fruit`, and `MaybePeel` types (although the last one needs to be changed to fix a logic error... maybe you want to just edit the question so I don't have to say this):

```
type MaybePeel<T extends Food> =
  T extends Fruit ? { peel: boolean; } : unknown // <-- not never

type EatParams = { [F in Food as F["name"]]: 
  { food: F, quantity: number } & MaybePeel<F> 
}[Food["name"]];
```

I don't want to digress to much in explaining that `EatParams` formulation other than to say it's a "distributive object type" as coined in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) involving [indexing into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).

---

Unfortunately this still doesn't work directly:

```
function badEat(params: EatParams) {
  if (params.food.name === "Peach" || params.food.name === "Apple") {
    if (params.peel) { } // error!
  }
}
```

That's because [equality checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#equality-narrowing) of `params.food.name` only affects the apparent type of `params.food.name`.  It doesn't affect the type of `params`, because even though `EatParams` is a union, it's not considered a [*discriminated* union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).  Discriminant properties must be top-level. TypeScript doesn't support "nested" discriminated unions as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#18758](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18758). So `params.foodName` would possibly work, but `params.food.name` won't do anything.

---

At this point you have a few options.  One is to refactor so that the input to `eat()` is a genuine discriminated union by adding a `foodName` property or something up at the top.

Another is to give up on discriminated unions and instead use your existing union, along with a [custom type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) that simulates nested discriminants.  Possibly like this:

```
function isFoodType<T extends Food["name"]>(
  e: EatParams, type: T
): e is Extract<EatParams, { food: { name: T } }> {
  return e.food.name === type
}
```

This accepts an `EatParams` parameter `e`, as well as the name of a food type `type` of generic type `T`.  And the function acts as a type guard to narrow `e` from `EatParams` to either the member where the `food.name` property is of type `T` (if it returns `true`), or to the members where it is *not* of type `T` (if it returns `false`).

Then you write your `eat()` function like this:

```
function eat(params: EatParams) {
  if (isFoodType(params, "Peach") || isFoodType(params, "Apple")) {
    if (params.peel) { } // okay
  } else {
    params.peel // error
    // Property 'peel' does not exist on type '{ food: Pizza; quantity: number; }'.
  }
}
```

Looks good; the compiler knows that `params` must have a `peel` property in the true branch, and that it is not known to have a `peel` property in the false branch.

---

From the caller's side, this also (mostly) works as expected.  Good calls are allowed:

```
eat({ food: { name: "Pizza" }, quantity: 1 }) // okay
eat({ food: { name: "Apple" }, quantity: 1, peel: true }) // okay
```

and obviously bad calls are rejected:

```
eat({ food: { name: "Apple" }, quantity: 1 }) // error
```

The following call is *allowed*:

```
eat({ food: { name: "Pizza" }, quantity: 1, peel: true }) // okay
```

You might expect `peel` to be prohibited here due to it being [an excess property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks), but excess property checking only happens in some situations. In this case you are using a non-discriminated union, and "cross-term" properties are not considered excess in such cases. See [microsoft/TypeScript#35890](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35890) for more information.

That's hopefully not much of an issue, since excess properties are rarely a *type safety* problem.  The `eat()` function implementation will essentially ignore `peel` if it's passed in.

If it is an issue and you want to *prohibit* a defined `peel` property for pizza, then you should change `MaybePeel` to something like

```
type MaybePeel<T extends Food> =
  T extends Fruit ? { peel: boolean; } : { peel?: never }
```

at which point you will get an error on a `peel` of any type but `undefined`, and while `params.peel` will no longer be an error inside `eat()`, the compiler will know that it is `undefined` in the pizza code block.

---

That's pretty much it.

One last thing: you can't [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) `params` like `const { food } = params;` and expect the compiler to maintain the correlation between the types of `food` and `params` afterward.  There is some support for [destructured discriminated union types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions) but this won't help you since your type isn't a discriminated union.  And even if it were, you'd need to destructure all the properties, not just `food`. And you can't do that with a [rest property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#rest_property) at least until and unless [microsoft/TypeScript#46680](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46680) is implemented.  Right now the only way to do this is to just use `params` directly instead of trying to alias one of its properties.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=47&pln=24&pc=46#code/C4TwDgpgBAgmYBtoF4oG8oDsCGBbCAXFAERyITFQC+AUKJFAAoTYDGAFlKhjvkcczbtKtetEYBLAF5TsXdFjyESkmdhE064aADEA9noAm8skigAfJiw4Wm02VoY6ATgFcJwE-DOXBHTWJQALLYIABGEMwQCAA8ACpQEAAewBCYhgDOUPpGAHxcNFBQCcmp6Vku7p4A-AqQ0URhBkjYmADc1FBErpgA1ph6AO6YUAD0o1AxALRTWHqemBAAbhDOAdpQAKLYwIzYznhZyIUKAGYGhkSmEB0Ajq6twB4gRJiuuBHOHfUIjc0s7U65hOGHORiIfnYdwemCeoFe70+3wgDSgTT0LUBVAsIKgYMudjU0MezwRH1WHSobU0owAVI5oNtdvtDvIMABtHRQCQjHLGbAVdnEXgUAC6oqIoIuRB0ABooPcSfCsIjVp0AGTBUIRKKxHT5Kici5CkXEcXUulQQJMvYHXBHKAnKAACil4Ng3huCphcJeKvJX2xmowPz+GIBlIAlLYna68dKrEJibDSf6kUG6ijfmj-q0ozGii63QTVLJk76yeno7TRppTj1WE89CMwthDEznWAWfaiDbuxlo2gThJTi6u3aMgA6fGTkVcZCoATWYQWSzjw7Ti6zpTzxfXYiDp3c0ed-uTn6DzrjRLOZx6ZwAQhOtFodYbTZGEgyfLi2niiRSNJMmyY1hSUM1cmdE5lD7Cd5TEIg4hoSMiGgL8thSA5GxiWDDnlYtJUUPhik6Kh8iHIpnAgYBXGcEYIE3Ixt3wXcrW0GhXxoetMEbCRm0SHZTwnXsdltQ5DyKEcXS-H9tCEvCVGXA9V25b8Ll-SB5PteVSE9A8JMLKStKnC8FGxa89F6UJn0SBAMmgCjC3Xe1zyzMYJlWO81kLdymDvSBnFAKAAHIfmCqBDD0CAsgGTxki-Tx+MCYKCMJMtvSVP03gDSlgsnZ8OM0FhgDjfFCJFfhS3Uah5UVFNlQARmoaMLKskAaGK0qEx4JR+H3GqMvqv0GvlUMrTcaAqBaiZLOszrUp64iBHsaqqFqn1UxGqAxuACbmt8gYby8tEIFYbBXHsgDWGirIwH81YnmiqB9mgWLtrvdgJDCDwIGMfiBkwKZDC-VhnAkXAeR2X6oB6PjMAyeV7OgdhgGAMAMgIcYAHMPHYVwwknVg9FwUYIdBvQMj0U5gFGDSIAAZVBiQwBpr8MlcaLRgAZgAVgADgATgABg6wSFqI5RdPIER1syogmqm3zPPvGggA)

Comment: Thank you again for this excellent answer, it has filled a lot of gaps in my TypeScript knowledge.

Comment: While implementing your solution, I tried out the [ts-pattern](https://github.com/gvergnaud/ts-pattern) library, and it makes the code _much_ cleaner. I still took many of your suggestions; the library just makes the code much more terse. If you're interested, I'm happy to provide an example of what I did.